# 2 hour boot to Windows login?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, troubleshooting

When I turn on my Windows 10 Lenovo Ideapad 330 laptop, the screen is black with a 'Please wait' notice for 30 minutes. After 30 minutes the familiar scenic image comes up (i.e. desert mountain range) with the time and date in the bottom left and a (connected) wifi emblem with power icon on the bottom right. However the password box does not appear in the middle of the screen for a further 90 minutes.
Once I enter the password, it takes me to the Windows desktop with no delay and Windows then performs relatively normally.
In total then, it is a 2hr boot process from turning on the computer to finally getting to the Windows desktop.

I’ve been troubleshooting this issue for over 6 months to no avail.
Of course I could do a wipe and reinstall Windows, but I still remain curious about this issue.

Today, I’m here for just one reason - does anybody know of a tool/method to help display on screen in real time each process/driver/program etc, that is being loaded from the moment the laptop is first turned on? (Perhaps this might help me track down what is causing the delay...)

ADDITIONAL:
Thanks for your responses! This is not my main computer and I have all the files backed up. In 6 months of troubleshooting I've run Chkdsk, used Safe Mode, disabled fast boot, accessed BIOS and run other utilities. I've followed exhaustive troubleshooting from Google. (I’m still analyzing event logs & processes). When Windows finally does load, it runs a little slow but with its 8GB RAM I am ok with the performance. My focus is the 2 hours boot up time BEFORE getting into the Windows desktop. If anybody is aware of a tool/method to trace (with messages on screen in real-time) what is happening in those 2 hours, I'm still all ears...

Comment: You should try Safe Mode https://support.lenovo.com/hn/en/solutions/ht105328-f8-or-fn-f8-key-not-able-to-enter-safe-mode-in-windows-10-thinkpad It will give you a bit more information on what the PC is doing while its booting.

Comment: After the computer has fully booted, is it still slow?

Comment: Can you enter BIOS/UEFI (Firmware) by pressing related keys like F2, F12 or DEL at POST? After it completely boots to Windows, check the health of your HDD / SSD? Is it normal/good? Disable FAST Boot if you have enabled it in Power Options.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Have you bothered looking through the system logs to see what it was attempting to do with that window of time?  Not fool proof.. but probable that you will see something in the system log.

Comment: I recommend a fresh install of Windows.  There is some... interesting software and services running.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have an Ideapad, but the one I did have had a similar issue. In addition to the hard drive, it had a small SSD like device that was supposed to boost startup times. When that little device failed, boot up took forever. I removed it and boot up returned to normal times. I'm sorry I can't remember the details anymore, but maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks Mr. J... I only have a 1TB HDD (no SSD). But I do appreciate you taking the time to assist!

Answer (score -2):

First thing to do is to replace the hard drive with an SSD.

You could start with a chkdsk /r c:
However, if your hard drive is in bad shape like I think it is then it could take days for it complete.

You could try using http://hdd.by and downloading Victoria.  You will have to use google translate as the website is in Russian.

90% of the sectors should be in the 1st category usually 25 (ms).
5% being in the 2nd.

If you see a lot of green,red,black, or etc your drive is near failure backup now before you lose everything.

Comment: HDD to SSD is not a 30 minute difference.  I have a crappy old Athlon with an crappy HDD that boots windows 10 in seconds.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Comparing a SSD to a new hard drive would not make a 30 minute difference.  However if you have bad and/or weak sectors the hard drive can easily dwell on each error for a long time.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you.  You have clearly been doing this for a long time.  Perhaps the chkdsk suggestion alone might have done the trick.  I don't agree with telling them to spend money on a new drive even though it *probably* isn't the drive.  It could EASILY be timing out on any number of things (to include the drive).  One command later, and we would all know.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  The problem with chkdsk is it doesn't fix physically damage or age.  It HIDES the bad sectors so windows doesn't use them.  Sectors that are wearing out, and are generally just slow it ignores.  If his drive is this bad it is probably about to fail, and they risk losing ALL their data.

Comment: I completely agree.  I have been doing this since MFM drives.  I get how they work.  What I was saying is that it might not have anything to do with the drive.. and they might be ok with the performance otherwise.. and they might be broke.  I think we both agree.. but don't ;)  Thanks for your service to SU.